# Why does MATLAB tell me the length of the string '01' is 1?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array `ab`, where `ab(1)='01'`. MATLAB gives me that `length('01')=2`, but that `length(ab(1))=1`. Why is this? How can I make it not so?

Comment: @natan I have: K>> ab(1)
ans = 
    '01'

Comment: is ab a cell array or a regular array? type `class(ab)` and see

Comment: @natan ab is a cell array

Comment: it must be a cell array.

Comment: should I cast it to another type?

Comment: I've copied my comment to an answer below... the best thanks is to accept the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the length of the first element in cell array `ab` is 1, because it is a single element. If you want the length of the contents of that element you need to use curly brackets, such as, `length(a{1})` .